# Symfony Backend showing 404

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have generated the Backend Application for the Symfony(1.4 and ORM Propel) project, in my Production env. But on calling the URL as http://www.mydomain.com/backend.php it is showing 404. Is there any config error or something like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was due to the Permission of the file i.e backend.php. I have changed the Owner/Group permission and the backend app started working. If any one had this kind of a problem, please check the file permissions, might help!

Answer (score 2):

Look inside your web folder and make sure that backend.php actually exists there, it might have been named something else [typo maybe]. Does mydomain.com work ?

**Update**

Disable/rename your .htaccess file temporarily and see if this fixes it. It looks like mod_rewrite is catching "backend.php" and passing it on as a module name.

Comment: it exists..as project_name/web/backend.php and /backend_dev.php. both the files are existing...how come it is not getting it, i dont know..

Comment: yeah! the project works..as i can access my modules..and default modules also loads..

Comment: it is showing the Custom 404 and not the Symfony Default one..but not a default browser 404. But at 127.0.0.1 it is showing(i.e the backend.php's default page) in both env...

Comment: yes! it is a Module which is been set as custom 404 by changing in config file.

Comment: no its not a problem with .htaccess file i think, cos i created a dummy file as "abc.php" and called it, it worked! it showed that file.

Comment: hmm, take another look @ your routing.yml file, run the contents through a yml validator.

Comment: @sjobe i have found the solution, actually it was due to the permission of the backend.php file, i changed the owner,and group to site user and thus solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

For rendering 404 page, the third parameter in your front controller must be false.
Like this:

```
ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('backend', 'dev', false);
```

Comment: yeah thats right in case of custom error page, but my problem was with the permission as we had two user group with server. Thank You sandip. (plz dont remove the posted answer...)